# The band structure of Weyl Semimetals

Tags: fermions, electronic-band-theory, quasiparticles, weyl-semimetal

Weyl semimetals are topological quantum materials whose low energy excitations emerges as massles Weyl Fermions. They have a band touching point near the Fermi level called Weyl node.

[image]

What is actually the energy dispersion relation of Weyl Fermions? More specifically, do we have to consider the band as a linear dispersion relation or as a conduction and valence band which takes the shape of two cones?

I came up with this doubt because if we consider the band dispersion relation as linear, then

$$E_k=C\times (k-k_0)$$(For convenience consider 1D. but I know that Weyl semimetals are three dimensional)

then the effective mass is given by $$m*=\frac{\hbar^2}{\frac{\partial^2E_k}{\partial k^2}}$$

that gives

$$m*=\frac{\hbar^2}{0}=\infty$$

Which contradicts the fact that Weyl Fermions are massless.

But If we consider it as the latter one then the derivative is not defined at the Weyl node?
Where am I wrong in my calculations and concepts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weyl semimetals (WSMs) are realized when non-degenerate bands cross at isolated points in the Brillouin zone. Consider the simplest example of a time-reversal symmetry broken WSM modeled by the hamiltonian $$H = t' \sin{k_x} \sigma_x + t'' \sin{k_y} \sigma_y + t (\cos{k_x} + \cos{k_y}+ \cos{k_z} - M) \sigma_z.$$ This hamiltonian admits 2 bands ($\sigma_j$ are the Pauli matrices). When $1 < M < 3$ a WSM phase is realized with Weyl points (i.e. points where the two bands cross) at $(k_x, k_y, k_z) = (0, 0, \pm \cos^{-1}(M-2))$.

If you zoom-in close to one of the Weyl points (say the one at $k_z >0$), Taylor expand the terms in the hamiltonian in terms of the deviations $\delta k_j$, and keep only the leading order term in each expansion, then you'll find the following effective hamiltonian $$H_+ = t' \delta k_x~ \sigma_x + t'' \delta k_y~ \sigma_y - t \sin\cos^{-1}(M-2) ~\delta k_z~ \sigma_z.$$

At zero density, the Fermi level will intersect the Weyl points, and the *low* energy excitations will be described by $H_+$ (here, "low" implies energies at which the quadratic terms that were dropped in the Taylor expansion are small compared to the linear terms). Notice that these excitations disperse linearly, and has 2 branches. In this sense the low energy excitations emulate Weyl fermions.

If one ignores the higher order terms in the Taylor expansion entirely, then the low energy excitations appear to be *massless* owing to an absence of terms $\propto \delta k_j^2$. In reality there is a finite but small mass. Here, we need to distinguish between the 'band mass' ($m_*$), which is a measure of the local curvature of a band, from the particle-like excitation's mass which is the energy gap in the excitation spectrum: If the excitation spectrum is described by $ E(k) = \sqrt{k^2 + \mu^2}$, then $\mu$ is the mass/energy gap. It is $\mu$ that is usually alluded to when the term *massless* is invoked in the context of semi-metals or multiband insulators.

It is instructive to check these limiting behaviors with the eigenvalues (bands) of the microscopic hamiltonian, $H$. Make special note of the terms being dropped from the Taylor expansion.